# Turn on torch when camera is open

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I need to turn on torch when camera is open.

```
class FlashLight(private val context: Context) {
    private val cameraManager by lazy { context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager }
    private val backCameraId by lazy { cameraManager.cameraIdList[0] }
    
    fun turnOnFlashLight() = changeFlashStatus(shouldBeTurnedOn = true)

    fun turnOffFlashLight() = changeFlashStatus(shouldBeTurnedOn = false)

    private fun changeFlashStatus(shouldBeTurnedOn: Boolean) {
        try {
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(backCameraId, shouldBeTurnedOn)
        } catch (e: Exception){
            L.e(e)
        }
    }
}
```

My code is working when camera is closed but when I run camera inside my app and want to turn torch on I get error:

> android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_IN_USE (4):
> setTorchMode:2325: Torch for camera "0" is not available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enable torch in the same session with your camera.
You can enable the flash mode using this key

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#FLASH_MODE and set the value as https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#FLASH_MODE_TORCH

Comment: You also have to switch AE_MODE to be just AE_MODE_ON, not AE_MODE_AUTO_FLASH or AE_MODE_ALWAYS_FLASH.